# Cisco - Change both source and destination on NAT

Tags: cisco, nat

Note: As usual I'm dealing with single device so there are limits on what I can change outside of this router.

```
Device: Cisco 1841
IOS: 12.4(13a)
Vlan1 - IP: 192.168.0.3
Vlan1 (Default Gateway): 192.168.0.1
External: A.B.C.D:2222
Target: 192.168.0.50:1111
```

Basically, I'm trying to do a traditional "port forward", and translate an external A.B.C.D IP address into hitting a device on the internal network.

For example, I want...

```
Origin --> A.B.C.D |-Router-| 192.168.0.3 --> 192.168.0.50
```

To do this, I've configured the standard

```
nat inside
nat outside
ip nat outside source static tcp A.B.C.D 2222 192.168.0.50 1111
```

The problem, is that due to NAT rules, only the destination is being translated. This successfully takes the A.B.C.D destination address, and translates it into 192.168.0.50, reaching the target. The hang up is that the source has *not* changed, and is still set to A.B.C.D.

This is an issue, because the default gateway at 192.168.0.1 *cannot* route to A.B.C.D. If I can translate the *source* address at the time of NAT, making it 192.168.0.3, the packet will successfully make its way back to the interface, as 192.168.0.1 will understand how to route it.

I've attempted to set up a second NAT rule, however it seems on this Cisco device it only hits the first rule and then continues on.

**So my question is: How can I translate both the source and destination at the time of NAT, or before it leaves the interface via some other routing trick.**

Comment: "_This is an issue, because the default gateway at 192.168.0.1 cannot route to A.B.C.D._" Why not? If it can receive packets sourced with that address, it should be able to send packets destined to that address out the same interface on which they are received if you put in a static route. It sounds like you are trying to substitute NAT for routing.

Comment: As far as I can tell it does not have a route set up to handle going from 192.168.0.1 to A.B.C.D. This has been diagnosed by two methods. (1) issuing a ping to 192.168.0.1 two times, one with 192.168.0.3 as a source, one with A.B.C.D as the source. The first is successful, the second is not. (2) I can telnet to the target device because it’s issuing the request from the 192.168.0.3 address. This is successful. _Absolutely_ the correct thing would be to adjust the route on the gateway; but I have zero control over that router. I’m left trying to solve it with the constraints I have.

Comment: "_I have zero control over that router._" Unfortunately, questions about networks that you do no directly control are off-topic here. In any case, you would need to control the router in order to set up the NAT.